# Custom number of axis ticks D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've taken a look at a few different solutions to this problem but have been unable to find one that works. I am trying to set up an X-axis for a graph that has exactly 10 ticks (and then the the ends of the axis acting as ticks as well). I am using the following to try and do this:

```
var xValue = function(d) {
        return d.Time;
    },
    xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]),
    xMap = function(d) {
        return xScale(xValue(d));
    },
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
    .tickFormat("")
    .ticks(10)
    .orient("bottom");

xScale.domain([0, d3.max(tableData, xValue) + 1]);
```

However this only produces 8 or 16 ticks, and I can't seem to get it to produce the number I need. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.tickValues()` method on the axis to specify exactly what you want your ticks to be. With `tickValues`, you provide an array of ticks, which are exactly the ticks that will appear on the graph.

Your axis would look like this:

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale)
.tickFormat("")
.tickValues([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
.orient("bottom");
```

Of course, if you only have your max and min values, you will probably want to use a loop to populate the array, and then pass the final array as an argument to `tickValues`.

Comment: I needed to make it so that my tickValues matched my data, which this made me realize. So if my range is 0 - 100, I need to do 0, 10, 20, etc. Thanks!